# Total Differential based only on the outputs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential

I have this $f(x,y)$. $x$, $y$ and the output of of $f$ will always be positive numbers. $x$ and $y$ are independents. I am trying to find $df$, which is just ...

$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$

But I only have the inputs $x$ and $y$ and the output of $f$, the equations are hidden from me. So, I can only use the regular slope formula $(rise/run)$ to find the derivatives between x-axis and y-axis, such as ...

$$df=[f(3,5)-f(2,5)]+[f(3,5)-f(3,4)]$$
$$=(2403-12)+(2403-376)$$
As you can see, the output of $f$ is somewhat "random", it can be big or small, but the same $x$ and $y$ will yield the same output such as $f(1,3)$ will always produce $520$. So the question now is; am I correct on trying to find the derivative values by using the regular slope formula?

I am not trying to solve the equation or predict the future value, but I just wanted to be able to tell what is happening with the output as in "has $f$ increased or decreased?" and by finding the higher derivative I can answer the question "if $f$ has increased, is it stopping or continuing?".

Comment: You seem to have an incorrect understanding of what a derivative is. I mean this in the least offensive way possible, but I would recommend studying regular calculus a bit more before trying to understand partial differentiation.

Comment: @EthanMacBrough I see, thank you and I will learn more now. Do I have to delete the question though to prevent from others wasting their time coming here?

Comment: If you think there's a good reason not to delete the question, feel free to leave it up.